# What's a fast way to split an icon pack delivered as a psd?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, slices

I have downloaded the [Icon Sweets 2](http://iconsweets2.com/) icon pack and I cannot seem to fulfill the seemingly very easy task of exporting individual PNGs for each icon (contained in a separate layer). Using the built-in script takes about 5 minutes/ image which would result in about 33 hours required to export the whole image. I also tried slicing the image, but never managed to fit all the icons comfortably in a slice grid. Also, when trying to split the image into smaller slices, PS acts really strange. It only allows me to split the main slice (the image itself) horizontally or vertically but not both ways. This way I only ever get either 48px rows or columns, but never a grid of 48x48px slices ready to export.

I have spent hours trying to dig up a proper solution, and not ever the "export > render video" "hack" worked. Should I just let the slow built-in script run for 33 hours?

Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select every layer and with Layer>New Layer Based Slice make slices for every icon.

Then you have every icon extracted with its individual sizes. 
Now you can resize every icon with an action to get the canvas size right.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it works. It's just slow to work with, since I'm on a laptop. And there's hundreds of slices to save, hehe. Better than 24 hours though. :D

Comment: Hmm, this approach seems to have created a lot of extra, unnecessary slices, causing the output to be rather broken. It may be due to the fact that icons have slightly different dimensions.

Comment: Yes, the layer-based slice, didn't slice the smart objects dimensions but the actual visible pixels.
You can resize the canvas with an self-made action and (file>automate>batch)

Comment: Ahem, thanks for the tip! :D I'll see what I can do. I had just assumed, given that so many other icon packs are distributed as monolithic PSDs, that there was a quick and simple method to split everything which I had overlooked. Guess that wasn't the case, haha.

Comment: You could pre-slice it at design time :D

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not the author of the pack.

Answer (score 1):

As far as slices, if you drop guides and select the Slice tool, you should get a "Create slices from guides" button.

If the script is slow... get a faster computer? :) If not, yep, set it up on Friday night and come back on Monday.

Comment: Hehe, thanks for the tips! I just let it run on my machine. It now only seems to take 2-3 minutes/separation so it'll only take about 18 hours. :D

Answer (score -1):

Right click on layer and export as png

simple as that.

Comment: With over a thousand layers? Unless that also works with all layers selected (not at a computer at the moment, so I can't verify), that hardly seems a workable solution. And if you still have to go through the regular rigmarole of choosing/accepting both PNG export settings and file name for each layer, it's not a workable solution even if it does work on all selected layers.